# Print only non-empty variables, with conditional punctuation

Tags: ifthenelse

I have several variables.  I need to print those that are not empty.  The first variable printed must be preceded by some text.  If there are multiple variables printed, they must be separated by semicolons; the final (or only) variable must instead be followed by a period.  Nothing is to be printed if all variables are empty.

For example...

Blah: A; B; C.

Blah: D; N; X; Y.

Blah: W.

I have been using "\ifthenelse" with "\equal" to test and print the variables, but I've become lost in the nesting.  Is there a better way to accomplish this, perhaps some package that a layman can easily make use of, or must I buckle down and sort my way through the nesting issue?

Comment: It might also be a good idea to consider the tools in the etoolbox package, especially when you want to check whether a variable is missing or empty. Because of the various expansions using `\equal` is not straight forward

Comment: Also, welcome. And next time, consider posting some code we can use for testing (posted so we can copy and test as is without having to add anything)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\z{\ifhmode\ifnum\lastnodetype=0\hbox{;} \fi\fi}
\long\def\zstop{\ifhmode\unskip\setbox0\lastbox.\par\fi}


\begin{document}

{\everypar{Blah: }

\def\A{A}\def\B{B}\def\C{C}\def\D{}\def\N{}\def\W{}\def\X{}\def\Y{}\def\Z{}
\z\A\z\B\z\C\z\D\z\N\z\W\z\X\z\Y\z\Z\zstop

\def\A{}\def\B{}\def\C{}\def\D{D}\def\N{N}\def\W{}\def\X{X}\def\Y{Y}\def\Z{}
\z\A\z\B\z\C\z\D\z\N\z\W\z\X\z\Y\z\Z\zstop


\def\A{}\def\B{}\def\C{}\def\D{}\def\N{}\def\W{W}\def\X{}\def\Y{}\def\Z{}
\z\A\z\B\z\C\z\D\z\N\z\W\z\X\z\Y\z\Z\zstop


\def\A{}\def\B{}\def\C{}\def\D{}\def\N{}\def\W{}\def\X{}\def\Y{}\def\Z{}
\z\A\z\B\z\C\z\D\z\N\z\W\z\X\z\Y\z\Z\zstop

}

\end{document}
```